# use `union` with (For Each loop) without using array

Tags: excel, vba

on the below code. I select row on condition.
I need to use **union** to select all these rows with the below condition.
I know that my code can be changed completely by using arrays,
but for a learning purpose, how union can be used to do the same action?
In advance grateful for useful comments and answer.

```
Sub Union_Test()

  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, srg As Variant

Set rng = ws.Range("V3:V" & lastR)
    For Each cel In rng
     If cel.value = "Yes" Then
        cel.EntireRow.Select
     End If
 Next cel
 
     ' I need here to use union to select all (cel.EntireRow)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. It is not necessary/good to create a huge `Union` range (from the whole rows). You can create it only from the specific cells matching condition and then Select/Delete/Copy **its `EntireRow`**:

```
Sub Union_Test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
  Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, uRng As Range

 Set rng = ws.Range("V3:V" & lastR)
    For Each cel In rng
     If cel.value = "Yes" Then
        If uRng Is Nothing Then
            Set uRng = cel
        Else
            Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel)
        End If
     End If
  Next cel
  If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Now, if you want copying such a `Union` range, it will also not be good to copy the whole row matching the specific condition. In such a case you can intersect the `Union` range with sheet `UsedRange` and copy only the intersection...

Comment: Works perfectly . Please I need to learn why if I comment `Set uRng = cel` or `Set uRng = Union(uRng, cel)`  then the code select only one row , although by logic **one result** of If condition should run

Comment: @Waleed Such a range must be firstly created (somehow, if it is nothing)... So, the first (commented) line creates it **if nothing**. If you comment it the second line is never reached, because the range **IS** always nothing. It shows only one row, if you let `Set uRng = cel`. It practically will be build from only the first occurrence...

Comment: First, brilliant for understanding my mind. I tried your advice `Intersect` and works. I also tried other method `Offset with resize` but raising an error. Kindly advice. the range from A:AF

Comment: @Waleed I am afraid I cannot understand what you mean by **`Offset with resize`**...